# In Calculus: if we apply chain rule to $\frac{d}{dx} (y^4)$, why do we only apply the product rule on $\frac{d}{dx} (x^2y)$?

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

If we apply chain rule to $\frac{d}{dx} (y^4)$, because there's a function within a function.

Why do we only apply the product rule on $\frac{d}{dx} (x^2y)$?

Comment: It is only a product of two functions. Where/how would you want to apply the chain rule?

Comment: Because the power of $y$ is $1$!

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)$ by itself is a function within a function and we would have to use chain rule right? Just because we multiplied it with y, the chain rule doesn't apply anymore. It for some reason doesn't click for me. How do I get the intuition to apply the chain rule or product rule. What about $\frac{d}{dx}((x^2y)^2)$, do we use chain or product rule?

Comment: You wouldn't have to use the chain rule for your first example. It's a function with a known derivative, $2x$. What would be the functions you'd want to chain? $x$ and $x^2$? Because then you'd still need to know the derivative of $x^2$.

Comment: I think I'm narrowing down my confusion now.. Why does $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)$ apply power rule. But $\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)$ apply chain rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function can be with the following functions:
$$ f(x)  =  x^4$$

$$ g(y) =  y$$

As:

$$ f( g) = y^4$$

Hence,

$$ \frac{df(g)}{dx} =  \frac{df}{dx}|_{g(y)}  \cdot \frac{dg(y)}{dx}$$

Then,

$$ \frac{df(g)}{dx} =  4y^3 \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$$

The other example:

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(x^2 y) =  y \frac{d}{dx} x^2 +  x^2 \frac{d}{dx} y $$

Since

$$ \frac{d}{dx} y = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

There is no reason to chain rule.

Comment: Going to accept this answer because I reckon I need to confirm my confusion in another question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The product rule
$$ \frac {\mathrm d (u(x)v(x))}{\mathrm dx}=u'(x)v(x)+u(x)v'(x)$$
**is** the chain rule
$$D(f\circ g)=Df\cdot Dg$$
applied to $g(x)=(u(x),v(x))$ and $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm narrowing down my confusion now.. Why does $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)$ apply power rule. But $\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)$ apply chain rule?